# what is telescopic Mos load

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, cmos

i have a design project, which includes designing a single stage amplifier (cmos device) i have to use **telescopic** **p mos load** to design degenerated common source single stage amplifier.
what exactly is a **telescopic** **load**, i have tried googling it but all i found out was about telescopic op-amp , telescopic cascode.
Any help would be appretiated

Comment: I would presume that you are supposed to use a simple cascaded PMOS load ?

Answer (score 1):

It probably refers to a non-folded cascode "telescoped" with a diffamp [like this](https://books.google.com/books?id=y50SBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA260):

[image]

But you should really ask at office hours (for your class) to be certain.

Comment: could you share the source

Comment: It's linked in the answer. If it somehow doesn't work it's *Analog Design for CMOS VLSI Systems* by Franco Maloberti.

Comment: You can also find more details in [these free lecture slides](http://www.aicdesign.org/SCNOTES/2010notes/Lect2UP240_(100328).pdf)